# Why is the Parse Class not saving?

Tags: php, ios, parse-platform, sdk

I am building an IOS app using a Parse database and have realised it would be useful to be able to connect to the database using PHP. I have downloaded the PHP SDK and set it up so that it is connecting. I can retrieve information and have even set a testObject so I do know the connection is valid. However I am having trouble updating an image in the User class. I have set the ACL to have public read and write access and am specifically trying to upload one image to one user account.

Can anyone who understands the syntax tell me why my code is not working?

I am getting the "Okay so far" message, so I know the failure is with the try catch but don't see why it's outputting neither success or error.

```
$file = ParseFile::createFromFile("filename.jpg", "image.jpg", "image/jpg");
$file->save();

$getUser = new ParseQuery("_User");
$getUser->equalTo("objectId", "2Ic26GaYRE");
$results = $getUser->first();
$results->set("profilePic", $file);

echo "Okay so far";

try {
    $results->save();
    echo 'success';
}
catch (ParseException $ex) {
    echo 'error';
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option A**
I would suggest using cloud code to modify users. You can make a cloud function in javascript on your parse server by editing the cloud/main.js file.

Basically, you can create a function like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("modifyuser", function(request, response){
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo('objectId', request.params.objectId);
  query.find({
    useMasterKey: true,
    success: function(results){
      if(results.length>0){
        var user = results[0];
        user.set("SOMEPARAMETER",true);
        user.save().then(
            function(result){
            },
            function(error){
                console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            });
        }
      }
    },
    error: function(error){
            response.error('query error: '+ error.code + " : " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

And call this function from your client.

```
$ParseCloud::run("modifyuser", ["objectId" => "THEUSEROBJECTID"]);
```

**Option B**
You can try this php version!

```
$file = ParseFile::createFromFile("imagePath.jpg", "image.jpg", "image/jpg"); 
$file->save(); 

     try { 
        $query = new ParseQuery("_User"); 
        $query->equalTo("username", "myUsername"); 
        $results = $query->find($useMasterKey = true); 
        foreach($results as $user) { 
          $user->set('email','me@myEmail.com'); 
          $user->set('profilePic', $file); 
          $user->save($useMasterKey = true); 
        } 
     }
    catch (ParseException $error) { 
        echo 'Error message: '.$error->getMessage(); 
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid that hasn't worked for me. Is that tried and tested code? If it is, there must be something up at my end... This is so frustrating! :)

Comment: Sorry that was for parse.com. Try now. When using parse-server  the users table will always require $useMasterKey = true. I updated my answer

Comment: Make sure you passing master key in your initialization

Comment: Dan test it now and see how you go! Option A works and b should too!

Comment: your code modfiy  $results = $getUser->first( $useMasterKey = true); and test that too

Comment: What PHP version should I be using? It's on 7.1

Comment: My initialize is using the third variable as the master key, is that correct? ParseClient::initialize('xxx', '', 'xxx');